# How to detect if user pressed back button with vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In vue router I want to detect when the url changes on history mode. However at times I manually push new urls on it, but I don't want those changes to be detected. Its more for when the user changes it using back/forward buttons.

Anyone know if there is a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

im not completely sure I got you, but if you want to run somthing every time the url changes, [vue router navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) can help you a lot (in `router.beforeEach` or  `router.afterEach` for example:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // everything you write here will get excuted whenever the route changes
})
```

)

to change the route, you probably know you can use `$router.push(options)` more about it here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: yes but how do you distinguish between me calling router.push to change the url vs me pressing the back button on the browser window which also changes the url?